# dict holds list - list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to collect list of conditional elements to dataframe query,
I manage to create it as below:

```py
column = ['TotalCharges',  'gender']
equal = ['>', '==']
condition = [ 20, 'F']
query = ' & '.join(f'{i} {j} {repr(k)}' for i, j, k in zip(column, equal, condition))
```

So Query output:

```
TotalCharges > 20 & gender == 'F'
```

Which is the required and correct ,

Im curious how to achieve same thing using dictionary holds list,
meaning

```py
df_query_params =  {"column":[],"equal":[],"condition":[]}
df_query_params["column"] = ['TotalCharges',  'gender']
df_query_params["equal"] =  [ '>', '==']
df_query_params["condition"] = [20, 'F']
```

I tried similar approach, with `df_query_params.keys()` and also `df_query_params.items()` but it doesn't work,

The things that makes me little lost with list comprehension
is that i don't know how to "gradually" add more nested elements,

Comment: Where's the list comprehension? I see a generator expression and some list literals, but no list comp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you just want the same query using comprehension for the given dictionary, one way would be to iterate through the values of the dictionary using zip, and join in similar fashion.

```py
>>> ' & '.join(f'{i} {j} {repr(k)}' for i,j,k in zip(*df_query_params.values()))
"TotalCharges > 20 & gender == 'F'"
```

Comment: Note that dict ordering isn't guaranteed on [Python 3.6 or lower](/q/39980323/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to swap out the bare names.

```
query = ' & '.join(
    f'{i} {j} {repr(k)}'
    for i, j, k in
    zip(
        df_query_params["column"],
        df_query_params["equal"],
        df_query_params["condition"])
    )
```